# NGINX redirect to another page on the same domain

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect mobile users to a specific page on site.

The desktop url is **http://www.example.com** but when it detects the user is using a mobile it should redirect to **http://www.example.com/mobile**.

I tried something like the following, but although the url changed, it says that it redirects too many times.

```
set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

if ($http_user_agent ~* "|android|ip(ad|hone|od)|kindle") {
 set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
 return 301 http://www.example.com/mobile;
break;
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're creating an infinite loop of redirects. The 301 is redirecting, but then when the mobile URL is loaded, the rule is being triggered again. Can you include an earlier `location` rule for `/mobile` that does not include the $mobile_rewrite rule?

Comment: How do I do it? I tried adding a condition that checks if the url is already on /mobile and stops it from redirecting but it fails. I'm really sorry this is my first time playing around with nginx configs.

Comment: Post your complete config?